# Issue trying to delete space in Excel

Tags: excel, space

I'm trying to delete this space "26 %" and I just can't. I've tried the subsitute formula and the replacement and I can't get it to be 26% without that space in between the % and the 26.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a NBSP char(160)

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),"")
```